# Running prop.table on entire DF

Tags: r

So I am trying to  run frequencies on a customer survey. The survey had 108 variables, and the responses are coded 1-5, with 9 being our NA. A few of the variables are text based. The raw data looks like this:

```
Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  3  2  Mazda
2  3  4  Ford
3  5  2  Toyota
9  3  2  Hyundai
```

Ideally I want to know how many people responded to each question in this format for each of the 108 variables. For example, the first column in my new data frame would be:

```
Q1
1  25%
2  25%
3  25%
4  0%
5  0%
9  25%
```

I've tried using

```
Frequencies = apply(df, 2, table)
```

It spits it out as a list. I'd like to then run this list though

```
prop.table(Frequencies, 2)
```

to get the column percentages. However, I get the error "Error in margin.table(x, margin) : 'x' is not an array."

I've played around for a few days with transforming Frequencies into a data frame but have had no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

PS: I've been working on this for four days and couldn't find a solution online. I'm sorry it's so basic. I'm very new at this.

Comment: Please post a small reproducible example.

Comment: I've updated with a small sample of my data. Is that what you were asking for? @Glen_b

Comment: Is each question a rating on a scale of 1:9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
> ddf
  Q1 Q2 Q3      Q4
1  1  3  2   Mazda
2  2  3  4    Ford
3  3  5  2  Toyota
4  9  3  2 Hyundai
> 
> sapply(apply(ddf, 2, table), function(x) x/sum(x))
$Q1

   1    2    3    9 
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 

$Q2

   3    5 
0.75 0.25 

$Q3

   2    4 
0.75 0.25 

$Q4

   Ford Hyundai   Mazda  Toyota 
   0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25
```

Or, as @DavidArenburg has suggested in comments:

```
lapply(ddf, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
```

Comment: Why running a double loop? What's wrong with just `lapply(df, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))` ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are right. Since OP was already using apply(ddf, 2, table), I just tried to complete his code.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to format your columns as factors with the levels you care about.  Then you can use [?lapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) to apply a function to a list (data frames are a type of list).  You will need to write custom functions within the `lapply()` call to do what you want.  The output of `lapply()` is another list, so you can nest it within `as.data.frame()` to turn it back into a data frame when you set the factor levels.  For the last `lapply()` call, you would do best to keep it as a list, because otherwise R will [recycle](https://www.inkling.com/read/r-cookbook-paul-teetor-1st/chapter-5/recipe-5-3) the shorter outputs to make them the same length as the longer outputs.

```
df <- read.table(text="Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  3  2  Mazda
2  3  4  Ford
3  5  2  Toyota
9  3  2  Hyundai", header=TRUE)
dfQs    <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[,1:3], function(x){ factor(x, levels=c(1:5,9)) }) )
dfQs$Q4 <- as.factor(df$Q4)
dfQs
#   Q1 Q2 Q3      Q4
# 1  1  3  2   Mazda
# 2  2  3  4    Ford
# 3  3  5  2  Toyota
# 4  9  3  2 Hyundai
proportions <- lapply(dfQs, function(x){ prop.table(table(x)) })
proportions 
# $Q1
# 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 
# 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 
# $Q2
# 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 
# 0.00 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 
# $Q3
# 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 
# 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 
# $Q4
# Ford Hyundai   Mazda  Toyota 
# 0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25
```

Comment: (+1) this is almost the correct answer, apart that he doesn't need all 9 levels, just 1:5 and 9 (for NA). The second problem is that this is not a general solution and I don't think he is going to manually run all the categorical variables. To conclude, the general solution would be just `lapply(df, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) prop.table(table(factor(x, levels = c(1:5, 9)))) else prop.table(table(x)))`. And you don't need `as.data.frame` here as it seems the output lengths for each column will always differ, so just leave it as a list

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks for the tip about the levels, I had missed that. I prefer to do two explicit `lapply`s, rather than nest an `if` w/i an `lapply`. It does take more lines, but it's easier to see it unfold, IMO.